# Getting blank screen on mobile device test, after updating Ionic and Angular to latest version

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm restaring a project that I've been working around for 2 years, and after almost half a year without touching it, I updated both Angular and Ionic to the latest versions (as for today).

These migrations were easy and took almost no effort, and the app works perfectly on desktop. No errors or problems this far whatsoever.

Things get different when I test it on a phone: the screen gets white, and nothing else happens. When I analyze it with the Chrome Inspector (with USB debugging activated), I see the following error stack:

```
onscript loading complete
capacitor-runtime.js:361 TypeError: fn.bind is not a function
    at newTrustedFunctionForJIT (/vendor-es2015.js:10868)
    at JitEvaluator.evaluateCode (/vendor-es2015.js:10932)
    at JitEvaluator.evaluateStatements (/vendor-es2015.js:10906)
    at CompilerFacadeImpl.jitExpression (/vendor-es2015.js:24300)
    at CompilerFacadeImpl.compileNgModule (/vendor-es2015.js:24230)
    at Function.get (/vendor-es2015.js:116292)
    at getNgModuleDef (/vendor-es2015.js:90418)
    at assertNgModuleType (/vendor-es2015.js:90597)
    at compileNgModuleFactory__POST_R3__ (/vendor-es2015.js:118326)
    at PlatformRef.bootstrapModule (/vendor-es2015.js:118573)
capacitor.handleError @ capacitor-runtime.js:361
/vendor-es2015.js:10868 Uncaught TypeError: fn.bind is not a function
    at newTrustedFunctionForJIT (/vendor-es2015.js:10868)
    at JitEvaluator.evaluateCode (/vendor-es2015.js:10932)
    at JitEvaluator.evaluateStatements (/vendor-es2015.js:10906)
    at CompilerFacadeImpl.jitExpression (/vendor-es2015.js:24300)
    at CompilerFacadeImpl.compileNgModule (/vendor-es2015.js:24230)
    at Function.get (/vendor-es2015.js:116292)
    at getNgModuleDef (/vendor-es2015.js:90418)
    at assertNgModuleType (/vendor-es2015.js:90597)
    at compileNgModuleFactory__POST_R3__ (/vendor-es2015.js:118326)
    at PlatformRef.bootstrapModule (/vendor-es2015.js:118573)
/vendor-es2015.js:67688 Ionic Native: deviceready event fired after 60 ms
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://localhost/runtime-es2015.js.map: Connection error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://localhost/main-es2015.js.map: Connection error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://localhost/polyfills-es2015.js.map: Connection error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://localhost/vendor-es2015.js.map: Connection error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I'm currently using Capacitor instead of Cordova, and these are my dependencies:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~11.2.0",
    "@capacitor/android": "^2.2.0",
    "@capacitor/core": "^2.2.0",
    "@capacitor/ios": "^2.2.0",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^5.28.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.7",
    "@ionic-native/crop": "^5.28.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^5.28.0",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^5.26.0",
    "@ionic-native/image-picker": "^5.28.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.5.4",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.39.7",
    "@types/parse": "^2.12.1",
    "angularx-social-login": "^3.2.2",
    "cordova-android": "^8.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-crop": "^0.4.0",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker": "^2.3.5",
    "jetifier": "^1.6.6",
    "moment": "^2.26.0",
    "parse": "^2.13.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.1",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1101.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~11.2.0",
    "@capacitor/cli": "^2.2.0",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.1.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.1.5"
  },
```

Additional data:

```
OS: Windows 10
Node: v15.7.0
Device: Xiaomi Pocophone F2
```

What is causing this problem?

Comment: Please post the stacktrace instead of a link. Imgur is blocked for some people that can help you.

Comment: Of coure, thank you! I'll post it instead of the screenshot

Comment: Try updating these to the latest stable too: `@capacitor/core`, `@capacitor/ios`, `@capacitor/android`. And just to confirm, running `ionic serve` works?

Comment: Hello @johnborges, yes, I updated these to 2.6.0, but it still has the same error, though it's working perfectly with ionic serve.

Comment: Sorry, I meant 2.4.6!

Comment: My guess its probably an incompatible Cordova plugin then.